# Sending messages with HTML contents using the MAPI control in VB6

Tags: html, vb6, mapi

How can I send a mail using MAPI with an HTML body? I need to create table in a message body.
I'm using vb6 and the MAPI control. Any ideas?

```
Function MailSend(sSendTo As String, sSubject As String, sText As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    With MAPISession1
        If .SessionID = 0 Then
            .DownLoadMail = False
            .LogonUI = True
            .SignOn
            .NewSession = True
            MAPIMessages1.SessionID = .SessionID
        End If
    End With
    With MAPIMessages1
        .Compose
        .RecipAddress = sSendTo
        .AddressResolveUI = True
        .ResolveName
        .MsgSubject = sSubject
        .MsgNoteText = sText
        .Send False
    End With
    MailSend = True
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    'MsgBox Err.Description
    MailSend = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MAPI control uses Simple MAPI, which does not handle HTML. There is a trick when using Simple MAPI directly (MAPISendMail) - set the body to NULL and attach and HTML file: it will be used as the message body. I don't know if that trick will work with the MAPI control.

Why not switch to using the Outlook Object Model? It is perfectly capable of handling HTML:

```
set App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
set NS = App.GetNmaespace("MAPI")
NS.Logon
set Msg = App.CreateItem(0)
Msg.To = sSendTo
Msg.Subject = sSubject
Msg.HTMLBody = sYourHTMLBody
Msg.Send 'or Msg.Display
```

Comment: "set the body to NULL and attach and HTML file" got what I need :) Thanks. Love this forum.

Comment: This is no longer working with current Office version. Does anyone know how to implement it?

Comment: Use Outlook Object Model - see above.

Answer (score 1):

keep 
.MsgNoteText ="";
.AttachmentPathName = result

ie.

```
With MAPIMessages1
    .Compose
    .RecipAddress = sSendTo
    .AddressResolveUI = True
    .ResolveName
    .MsgSubject = sSubject
    .MsgNoteText =""
    .AttachmentPathName = "c:\yourHtml.html"
    .Send False
End With
```